# I need assistance on this line of PHP for school

Tags: php

I am unfamiliar with PHP and am very confused. The goal is to have a line that asks the user their name and if it is equal to "John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt" then it is to put out the last line. But on the last line it says there is an unexpected T_STRING.
The code is;

```
<?php
    echo "What is your name?";
    $name = readline();
    echo "Oh, that's a cool name I guess.";
    if $name = (John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt);
    echo "Your name is my name too!"; 
?>
```

Please help as much as you can. Thank you!

Comment: you want to ask the user their name and then you don't have any input fields.

Comment: You'd be better off using Ajax for this. Have a form with input fields. Then on submit, check for the specific name for a match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    <?php
    echo "What is your name?";
    $name = readline();
    echo "Oh, that's a cool name I guess.";
    if ($name == 'John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt'){
        echo "Your name is my name too!"; 
    }

?>
```

if $name is John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt print result.
echo $name is what comes..

Answer (score 0):

That's not how you build an if-statement. Please check the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php).
Your Code should be something like this:

```
if ($name == "John Jacob Jingleheimer Schmidt"){
    echo "Your name is my name too!"; 
}
```